# View pptx in our Android app

Tags: android, powerpoint

I have searched thoroughly but m unable to reach a solution on how to make pptx viewable in my app? Is there any library which i can add or any other solution because webview doesnt support this format?
I want to access my pptx file from my sdcard.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do will be to fire an Intent with a specific Uri, and let the phone chose an application that can open that file, if any.

Comment: thnx for ur ans...but i dnt want to use any third party software...and thinking from end-users' point of view.. i dnt want to prompt him for an "officesuite" type software to be installed first.

Comment: Then you can use Open apache project to view office files without any third party apps

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache POI project
[Apache POI Link](https://poi.apache.org/)

Comment: how active is Apache POI project?  Is it keeping up with MS, e.g., Office 365?